# Facebook JWT authentication using ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, facebook-authentication, bearer-token

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API to create application with authentication. I want to login using "login/password" combination and using Facebook. I am using JWT tokens for authorization. From `Startup.cs` I am calling extension method `RegisterAuth`.

```
public static void RegisterAuth(this IServiceCollection services, AuthSettings authSettings)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                ValidIssuer = authSettings.Issuer,
                ValidAudience = authSettings.Audience,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authSettings.SecretKey))
            };
        })
        .AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
        {
            facebookOptions.AppId = authSettings.Facebook.AppId;
            facebookOptions.AppSecret = authSettings.Facebook.AppSecret;
            facebookOptions.SignInScheme = "Bearer";
        });
}
```

In my controller I have 2 methods. `Login` for "login/password" combination which it works and returns me jwt token. And `SignIn` for facebook which does not work.

```
[Route("SignIn/{provider}")]
public IActionResult SignIn(string provider)
{
    return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties(), provider);
}
```

`SignIn` redirects to the facebook page from where after signing in it throws an exception.

> InvalidOperationException: No IAuthenticationSignInHandler is
>   configured to handle sign in for the scheme: Bearer

So please help me to fix Facebook Auth.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have to change Facebook SignInScheme and add cookies.

1) Change `"Bearer";` to `CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;` and add cookie.

2) After `AddAuthentication` add

```
.AddCookie()
.AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
{
    facebookOptions.AppId = authSettings.Facebook.AppId;
    facebookOptions.AppSecret = authSettings.Facebook.AppSecret;
    facebookOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});
```

Comment: Hi @gor-asatryan, I don't understand very well all authentication schemes, but I think in this case, you do not use JWT approach anymore but the Cookie one, no?

Comment: Yes. Using cookie authentication for facebook and jwt for login+password combination

Comment: How do you handle the Token/Cookie expiration use case with FB? or will it change only when the user Signed Out? or life time one?